# Kibana timelion: How to add vertical line

Tags: kibana, kibana-5, timelion

I have a chart displayed in Kibana timelion and I want to add vertical line
For horizontal lines it can be used `.value(200)` or `.static(200)` - is there any possibility to add vertical one?

Answer (score 1):

**I did this on 5.6.2. It's kind of hack way.**

> .es(q='date:[2017-12-01 TO 2017-12-02]', metric='min:Some_Test_Rate',
>   timefield='date').add(10).bars(2).color(red).label('Specific Date'),

- I have weekly data, so, I put the range like 2017-12-01 TO 2017-12-02. It just pick one date. (every Friday)
- And display any data. Adjust with add(10) to make it looks better. (You can use max as well)
- The others: .bars(2).color(red).label('Specific Date'), would be easy to understand.

Comment: pics or it didn't happen :)

Comment: Cannot make it work - does `date` expression is some generic or you must have it in index? Can you add example document on what this query is working?